# Not getting desired XPath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

To summarise, how can I get an XPath to scrape the odds in my script.

An XPath that gives different values.

groups = `".//div[contains(@class, 'gl-ParticipantOddsOnlyDarker gl')]"`

xp_ba3 = `".//span[contains(@class, 'gl-Participa')]"`

The XPath needs for both groups and xp_ba3 needs to be the same length and different for it to behave correctly (I believe).

Desired XPath looks like:

XPath: `//div[contains(@class, 'gl-Market_HasLabels')]/following-sibling::div[contains(@class, 'gl-Market_PWidth-12-3333')][1]//div[contains(@class, 'gl-ParticipantOddsOnly')]`.

This works but when I add this logic and run the [script](https://pastebin.com/wGXc1tvZ) -- it does not work.

Webpage [odds](https://ibb.co/fs7Hwb) I am after.

My output instead of different odds looks like:

```
[['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87'], ['2.87']]
```

How can I get the odds to work?

HTML:

```
<div class="gl-ParticipantOddsOnlyDarker gl-ParticipantOddsOnly gl-Participant_General sl-MarketCouponAdvancedBase_LastChild " >
        <span class="gl-ParticipantOddsOnly_Odds" > 2.45 </span>
    </div ><span class="gl-ParticipantOddsOnly_Odds">2.45</span>
```

from [website](https://www.bet365.com.au/#/AC/B1/C1/D13/E108/F16/S1/)

Comment: Share the relevant HTML please

Comment: @DebanjanB I added the html to the question.

Answer (score 0):

So the main problem is that their HTML is set up in columns instead of rows which makes it harder to get the correlated data.

For the game names, you can use a CSS selector

```
div.sl-CouponParticipantWithBookCloses_NameContainer
```

For the odds in 1, you need to use an XPath

```
//div[contains(@class,'sl-MarketCouponValuesExplicit33')][./div[contains(@class,'gl-MarketColumnHeader')][.='1']]//span[@class='gl-ParticipantOddsOnly_Odds']
```

The XPath is looking for the `DIV` that is the parent container for the columns. It then looks for the one that contains '1' in the header, and then gets the odds from only that one.

You might want to do some basic validation that the number of elements returned by each matches or your odds will likely not match up with the right games. They are currently returning the same numbers.